# Julia Int Value of a String

Tags: string, char, int, julia

I'm fairly new to the Julia language and am struggling to find the integer value of a string.

I know that calling int('a') will return the value I'm looking for, but I cannot figure out how to do the same for int("a").

Is there a way to convert a string value to a character?

UPDATE:
Yes, the solution you provided does work, but not in my case. I probably should have been more specific. Here is what my array of strings looks like

array = ["12", "13", "14"]
        ["16", "A"]

array[2][2] returns "A" not 'A'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the "String Basics" section of the Julia manual](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.2/manual/strings/#string-basics):

> ```
> julia> str = "Hello, world.\n"
> "Hello, world.\n"
> ```
>
> If you want to extract a character from a string, you index into it:
>
> ```
> julia> str[1]
> 'H'
>
> julia> str[6]
> ','
>
> julia> str[end]
> '\n'
> ```

So you can get the character at index `1`, and then pass that to `int`.

Comment: This actually helped a lot. fin_array[3][2][1]

Answer (score 4):

Strings are represented internally as an array of `Uint8`, so for `ASCIIString`s the following works:

```
julia> "Hello".data
5-element Array{Uint8,1}:
 0x48
 0x65
 0x6c
 0x6c
 0x6f
```

The definition of a character is more complicated for Unicode, however, so use this with caution.

Comment: No, rakh's response helped me figure it out.

fin_array[3][2][1] #this will return the character value